# How to create collapse and expand functionality between pageblocks in visual force

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I am tryin to create expand and collapse functionality between pageblocks.The scenario is when i click the collapse button in one pageblock ,it should render another pageblock.How this can be achieved ? I tried using java script but the pageblock is not displaying properly.
My current code is

```
 <apex:page >
  <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryCollapse}"/>
  <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryCollapse1}"/>
   <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jqueryCollapse2}"/>
   <apex:form >
   <html>
   <head>

   <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

   $(".header").click(function () {    
   alert("Loopafe");
   $header = $(this);   

   $content = j$header.next();    
    $content.slideToggle(100, function () {       
         $header.text(function () {           
         return $content.is(":visible") ? $(this).attr("src",      "https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/resource/1404298250000/Minus") : $(this).attr("src", "https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/resource/1404298250000/plusimg");
    }); 
});    
}); 
}); 
</script>
 <style> 
  .container .content {
  display: none;
 padding : 5px;
 }
 </style>
</head>
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="10" collapsible="True" >           
<div class="container">
    <img   src="XXg"class ="   header " />
          <div class="content">
         <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockSection columns="5"  >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Collapse"  id="theSecond1"/>
        <apex:inputText /> 
       </apex:pageBlockSection>               
     </apex:pageBlock>

  </div>
   </div>
        <apex:outputText value="First" id="theFirst"/>
        <apex:InputText />

    </apex:pageBlockSection>    
</apex:pageBlock>
<body>
 </body>
 </html>

  </apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```

Comment: Try visiting the jQuery site. I know this is a feature supported by their libraries. Quite honestly, I find it to be very annoying, but its your page.

Comment: I just happened to notice that you have different code in your 1st pageblock than in your 2nd. Only the 1st one calls the functions at the bottom of the page. `Closethis()` requires `var opid` to be present in the pageblock which you don't have in the 1st one. Your code isn't at all consistent to give what you have a chance to even work.

Comment: I have updated my code please chk it

Answer (score 9):

I assume you are trying to build a so called accordion. As @crmprogdev mentioned I would also recommend to use jquery for this task and not reinvent the weel. You should avoid to go with pure javascript. Have a look a this:

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

or as an alternative

http://plugins.jquery.com/collapsible/

you will need to adapt both to work pageblocks, but eventually it will work. Using jquery without plugin is third an option. Look at click(), show(), hide() and toggle().

Answer (score 0):

There is small script which I used in my project to collapse the pageblock setion by default

https://jonyforce.wordpress.com/

Comment: Yes, i have found a Jscript that will collapse a section by default so that if I  move the 3 fields to the new section and collapse it by default then the user won't see them and won't edit them unless they actually start playing around with the screen in which case they may find them.   Its a work around as best, there should be a way to just not have those fields on the screen at all and have the lookup filter still work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have found a Jscript that will collapse a section by default so that if I move the 3 fields to the new section and collapse it by default then the user won't see them and won't edit them unless they actually start playing around with the screen in which case they may find them. Its a work around as best, there should be a way to just not have those fields on the screen at all and have the lookup filter still work.